# What is a good way to prevent two JQuery datepickers from having overlapping dates?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, intervals

I have two datepickers which are used together to enter a start-date and an end-date (dt0 and dt1). The problem arises when dt0 is bigger or equal to dt1. What is a good way to stop the user from picking a day in dt0 or dt1 that makes the time interval become negative (dt1 - dt0 < 0)? It would be nice if this could happen before the actual date "change" event was triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of the firstDateTimePicker to update the [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) property of the second datetimepicker. Also you might need to change the value along with the minDate.